# Multitenancy vs Public data

Tags: google-app-engine, architecture

I am quite new to Multitenancy, and I am trying to implement the same in Google App Engine using Namespaces, though the first question might not be specific to GAE itself. So here are my questions:

1. In a multitenat architecture does all data have to be private? What I mean is can some data be private to tenat and some data can be public to all tenats? Like a process/object shared by all tenats of system.
2. Assuming question to answer "Some data can be private to some tenats and some can be public to all tenats" is YES. How are switches from public to private or vice a versa for an object in system handled (This is more specific to GAE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Multi-tenancy allows you to switch namespace at any time during request. So you can switch to private namespace and then back to public one.
2. APIs (datastore, task queue, memcache, etc..) are namespace-aware, so when you switch to certain namespace and cal API methods GAE will separate data from one namespace from the other. The most important thing to note is that Keys contain namespace, so you must be careful while serializing/deserializing them in different namespaces.

Comment: Peter, so how does it affects if we have to move object from one namespace to other (Let's say from private to public namespace?)

Comment: The key needs to be recreated, which means creating a new entity and deleting the old one.

Comment: @vishal.biyani You can't move data between namespaces - only create copies of it in other namespaces, and delete the original.